# Get count of col for all entries prior to the start of each month

Tags: postgresql

Given a dataset with two features: ID and created_at (date). What is the best ways to get the sum of all IDs that were created before the start of each month, for all months included in the dataset? Eg, the value for May,2021 would have to be the count of all IDs created in April, 2021 or earlier

Something like:

```
Year | Month | Count
--------------------
2019 | 3     | 5
2019 | 4     | 8
```

Comment: Please add some sample data along with output in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window function after calculating month wise total like below:
Example Table:

```
create table test (id int, created_at date);
insert into test values(1,'2021-06-13');
insert into test values(2,'2021-01-13');
insert into test values(3,'2021-02-13');
insert into test values(4,'2021-02-13');
```

Step 1: Calculate the month wise count:

```
select date_trunc('month', created_at) "month_", count(*) "count_" from test
```

Step 2: Use sum window function to calculate the sum of previous months on above query result.

Query

```
select 
extract(year from month_) "Year",
extract(month from month_) "Month", 
coalesce(sum(count_) over (order by month_ rows between UNBOUNDED preceding and 1 preceding), 0) "Count" 
from (
select date_trunc('month', created_at) "month_", count(*) "count_" from test
 group by 1) t1
```

Output:

```
Year    Month   Count
2021    1        0
2021    2        1
2021    6        3
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=7c24d94123752d37eeb05db049292a7d)